# Update table with the count of matching rows within the same SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, sql-update

I'm trying to update a row in a table where the value of that row (itemCount) is the count of rows in the same table that match another row (itemID), using Microsoft SQL server 2019.

eg.

```
rownumber | itemID | ItemCount
1         | Banana | NULL
2         | Apple  | NULL
3         | Banana | NULL
4         | Pear   | NULL
5         | Pear   | NULL
6         | Banana | Null
```

After running the code, the table should look like this:

```
rownumber | itemID | itemCount
1         | Banana | 3
2         | Apple  | 1
3         | Banana | 3
4         | Pear   | 2
5         | Pear   | 2
6         | Banana | 3
```

I've tried this:

```
select count(*) from mldatatest t left join mldatatest o on t.itemID = o.itemID group by t.itemID
```

however, it returns the square of the figure, i.e, if there are 3 items, it returns 9, if there are 5, it returns 25...
Which I could fix, but when I try to turn it into an update statement:

```
update mldatatest set itemCount= (select count(*) from mldatatest t left join mldatatest o on t.itemID = o.itemID group by t.itemID)
```

it fails with the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I finally tried this:

```
SELECT count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY itemID) AS total FROM mldatatest;
```

which returns the correct data, however, when I try to turn it into an update statement, as above, it throws the same error.

I've had a read of lots of similar posts on here, and while some were helpful, a lot seemed to be specifically for MySQL, excel, or other programs.

I'm not sure if I would have to use a temp table to resolve this, but would prefer if there was an easier method?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Use an updatable CTE.

Comment: Thanks @Thom A.
I'm not familiar with using CTEs, so I had a look, and, on one of the pages that suggested it, I found another suggestion that worked!
It was simply:
`UPDATE mldatatest
    SET itemCount= (SELECT count(*)
                FROM mldatatest t2
                WHERE mldatatest.itemID = t2.itemID)`
That returned the correct values for each row. I'm not sure where the original code failed, but thank you for your suggestion that led me to the correct way of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
update m
set M.ItemCount = S.total
from mldatatest m
inner join (
  select rownumber, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY itemID) AS total 
  from mldatatest
) as s on s.rownumber = m.rownumber
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uY0hiKuH)

Comment: Thanks @SelVazi.
Thom A's suggestion put me on the right path to solve it, although not with CTEs.
Thanks nonetheless, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a subquery update:

```sql
-- create data
select *
, CAST(NULL AS INT) as itemCount
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (1,' Banana','3')
    ,   (2,' Apple','1')
    ,   (3,' Banana','3')
    ,   (4,' Pear','2')
    ,   (5,' Pear','2')
    ,   (6,' Banana','3')
) t (rownumber,itemID,itemCountExpected)

-- Update by countNew
update t
set itemcount = itemcountNew
FROM (
    select *
    , count(*) over(partition by itemid) AS itemcountNew
    from #data
    ) t
```

Output:

| rownumber | itemID | itemCountExpected | itemCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | Apple | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Banana | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | Pear | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | Pear | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | Banana | 3 | 3 |

This has the benefit of only processing table once

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen. I appreciate your advice.
Fortunately, Thom A suggested using an updatable CTE... which, when I was reading up on, came across a suggestion that worked without using CTEs, joins or temp tables. The code is in my comment in reply to him.
I must have just had something wrong with my original code.
Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of ways to skin the cat. Your way with subquery works, it might be a bit worse performance-wise and is called a triangular join

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Thom A, his suggestion to use an updatable CTE led me to a Stackoverflow question where someone posted a suggestion that worked for me.
It didn't use CTEs, joins or temp tables.

It was:

```
UPDATE mldatatest
SET itemCount= (SELECT count(*) 
FROM mldatatest t2 
WHERE mldatatest.itemID = t2.itemID
```

and provides the correct results, unlike my earlier attempts.
Thanks for everyone's imput, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
update mldatatest
set ItemCount = cnt
from (select itemID, COUNT(*) as cnt from mldatatest group by itemID) a
    inner join mldatatest b
        on a.itemID = b.itemID
```